# Can this be done with a single SQL Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am not sure if this can be done with a single JOIN, but I basically have two tables with an ID column in common. To make it simple I'll say Table A just contains an ID while Table B contains an ID and Code.  There is a 1:M relationship between Table A and Table B, however it's also possible an ID from Table A is not contained in Table B at all.  I was hoping to have a query return every ID that exists in Table B within a particular code range, or does not exist in Table B at all.

I tried using a LEFT JOIN with something like:

`SELECT A.id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id AND b.code BETWEEN '000' AND '123'`

But, this still gives me the IDs that exist in Table B outside of the code range.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Give us some sampledata and results.

Comment: Pretty sure `Between` doesnt work like that.  `Between 0 and 123` makes some sense.  Add `and b.code is null` to get those that dont exist in `b`.

Comment: You should specify which `id` you want on the select `a.id` I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join, and filter the result to contain the codes in the range, and also the lines where there is no matching record in table B:

```
select
  A.id
from
  A
  left join B on B.id = A.id
where
  B.code between '000' and '123' or B.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE b.code IS NULL OR b.code BETWEEN ' ' AND '123'
```